# Expressões regulares C++

Tags: c++, regex

Tenho um texto com a seguinte formatação

> concept:personasia:toby_pizur:personasia:teste

Como faço para pegar de uma string com essa formatação, somente o texto depois do último dois pontos(:) ?
No exemplo acima, ficaria só com "teste".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testa esse código:

```
string palavraRetorno = "";
string palavra = "concept:personasia:toby_pizur:personasia:teste";
int indice = palavra.LastIndexOf(':');
if (indice >= 0)
    palavraRetorno = palavra.substr(índice + 1);
```

A ideia é pegar o "último índice" do `:` e pegar a *substring* depois dele.

Comment: Muito obrigado!! a função correta é a find_last_of, mas me ajudou muito me dando um norte.

Comment: Massa, @LucasVieira ;)

Answer (score 5):

O que pretende obter da `string` é bem fácil de obter sem expressões regulares, como o @rLinhares já mostrou.

Se no entanto quisesse fazer com expressões regulares, que eu não recomendo, poderia faze-lo com:

```
:((?!.*:).*$)
```

[Veja esta regex no regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Atomwj/1/)

Explicação:

```
:    - dois pontos
(    - o que vem a seguir é o que vai ser capturado no primeiro grupo
(?!  - que não tenha a seguir
.*:) - qualquer coisa e dois pontos
.*$) - continua o grupo de captura apanhando tudo até ao fim da linha
```

No código em c++ capturaria assim:

```
std::regex rgx(":((?!.*:).*$)");
std::smatch match;
std::string input = "concept:personasia:toby_pizur:personasia:teste";

if (std::regex_search(input, match, rgx))
{
    std::cout << match[1];
}
```

[Veja este código no Ideone](https://ideone.com/ANRAVe)

Comment: Resposta excluída ok. obg: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/288920/8063

Comment: @dvd Acho que fez o mais correto, face a forma como o site funciona :)